# auto-resize Full Page Background Image with jquery-backstrech

Tags: jquery-plugins, background, slideshow, fullscreen, jquery-backstretch

how can i modified this plugin http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/ to auto-keep the background ratio when windows is resize like http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/css-1.php.

> i like the smooth fade effect in "backstrech" i would like to keep
>   this plugin but if anyone have a better plugin that does what i'm
>   looking for with the smooth effect between images.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your Css file

```
html {
background: url(../img/pattern.png) fixed, url(../img/background-image.jpg) 50% 50% fixed no-repeat;
-moz-background-size: auto, cover; /* Firefox 3.6 */ 
background-size: auto, cover; /* Chrome, Firefox 4.0+, Safari 4.1+, Opera 10+ and IE9 */
```

}